# Exercise 4.2, Atiyah Macdonald

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, primary-decomposition

I'm having difficulties in showing that a radical ideal has no embedded primes. I know that a radical ideal $I\subseteq A$ ($A$ ring) is equal to the intersection of the minimal primes containing $I$. *If there were finitely many of these minimal primes $p_1,\dots, p_n$, such that their intersection was still $I$*, I would be done: I could suppose that $I=\cap_{i=1}^np_i$ was a minimal primary decomposition, and so the associated primes would be again $p_1,\dots, p_n$, that are all minimal. However $A$ is not necessarily Noetherian, so it doesn't seem that the assumption in *italics* is granted. So what should I do to overcome this problem? Thank you

Comment: The associated primes are the ideals which are the radicals of the primary ideals which appear in some minimal primary decomposition of $I$. (they are independent of the choice of the decomposition). So clearly the number of minimal primes of $I$ is finite.

Comment: Ok but if I start from a primary decomposition $I=\cap _{i=1}^nq_i$, and I consider the primes $p_i:=\sqrt {q_i}$, I'm not guaranteed that the $p_i$ are minimal primes over $I$

Comment: Yeah, but suppose this decomposition is minimal. By the uniqueness theorem we know that any minimal decomposition contains exactly $n$ primary ideals. But since $I$ is radical we have $I=\sqrt{I}=\sqrt{\cap_{i=1}^n q_i}=\cap_{i=1}^n p_i$, and this is also a primary decomposition of $I$. Now assume not all ideals are minimal, i.e for some $i\ne j$ we have $P_i\subseteq P_j$. Then we can reduce it to $I=\cap_{k\ne j} p_k$. Now reduce this last decomposition into a minimal decomposition, and so you get a minimal decomposition with less than $n$ primary ideals, a contradiction.

Comment: @Mark sorry if I bring up this question after a while, I had a doubt: we cannot say that if $I $ is radical then its unique minimal primary decomposition is the one made of prime ideals, right? It came to my mind seeing this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350227/primary-decomposition-of-a-radical-ideal). Thank you

Comment: A minimal primary decomposition is not unique in general. However, if $I$ is radical then there is some minimal primary decomposition which contains only prime ideals. (it follows by taking radicals in any minimal decomposition, just as I explained in the comment above)