# Primary decomposition of a radical ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, primary-decomposition

Let $R$ be an arbitrary (commutative) ring. Let $I \subseteq R$ be an ideal such that $I$ has a minimal primary decomposition $$I =\bigcap_{i=1}^s Q_i$$ with $Q_i$  $P_i$-primary ideal, $i=1, \dots,s$.

We know that $\sqrt I = 
\bigcap_{P \in \mathrm{Min}(I)}P$.
If $I$ is radical we can say:
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^s Q_i = \bigcap_{i=1}^s P_i=\bigcap_{P \in \mathrm{Min}(I)}P.$$
Can we conclude that $Q_i$ must be equal to $P_i$ for all $i=1, \dots,s$?

I see that there is a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1721542) about embedded prime ideals, but it only explains that, in the same hypothesis, the $P_i$'s must be minimal primes. I understood this statement, but I can't understand why in this case holds the equality $Q_i =P_i$.

Comment: The answer is no, if $I$ is radical we are guaranteed that it has a minimal primary decomposition made of prime ideals, but not that it is the only one. See also this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4343977/exercise-4-2-atiyah-macdonald?noredirect=1#comment9090162_4343977

Comment: In fact, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

$Q_i$ contains the intersection of all associated primes. In particular, $Q_i$ contains an associated prime (why?), say $P_j$. From $P_j\subseteq Q_i$ we get $P_j\subseteq P_i$ (why?). Then $P_j=P_i$ (why?). We get $P_i\subseteq Q_i$, so $P_i=Q_i$ (why?).